# Solving $2y=\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{2y}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Any way to solve this irrational equation in $\mathbb{R}$?
I think it has some artifice, but I do not see it
$$2y=\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{2y}}$$

Comment: Perhaps this question is better placed in stack overflow

Comment: Do you mean R or $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog  **R**

Comment: @juanmuñoz:  eyeballfrog means R the programming language or $\Bbb R$ the real numbers.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan .... **R** the real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Square it, clear the fraction, and you have a cubic.
$$8y^3=6y+1$$
[Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8y%5E3%3D6y%2B1) finds three real roots with complicated expressions, about $-0.76604, -0.17365,0.93969$.

Comment: ,come to this cubic equation, but how do I solve it by hand

Answer (score 0):

Since $y$ equals to a square root, $y$ is non-negative.

Notice $$2y = \sqrt{3+\frac{1}{2y}} \implies 4y^2 = 3 + \frac{1}{2y}
\implies 4y^3 - 3y = \frac12
$$
and for any $x \ge 1$, $4x^3 - 3x \ge (4x^2 - 3)x \ge 1$, we find $y \in (0,1)$.

Take a $\theta \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $y = \cos\theta$ and recall $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3\theta - 3\cos\theta$. Last equation becomes

$$\cos(3\theta) = \cos\frac{\pi}{3}\quad\implies\quad 3\theta = (2N \pm \frac13)\pi\quad\text{ for some integer N} $$

Since $\theta \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, this forces $\theta = \frac{\pi}{9}$ and hence $y = \cos\frac{\pi}{9}$

Comment: thanks , some way to express cos 20 º with radicals?

Comment: Yes, but it will involve taking cubic root of complex number which is pretty useless.

Comment: You could show me the procedure to learn, if your time allows it

Comment: That will be the standard Cardano method of solving cubic equation. see entry on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano%27s_method) and [brillant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/)